# SettingWithCopyWarning: When trying to modify the date format of two columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am trying to change the date formats of two separate columns `Order_Date`, `Ship_Date` in the dataframe to `dd-mm-yyyy` format. This is my python code.

```
# Importing library panda
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

df = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')
print(df)

# Find the duplicate rows except Row_ID
duplicateRows = df[df.duplicated(subset=["Order_ID", "Order_Date", "Ship_Date", "Ship_Mode", "Customer_ID",
                                         "Customer_Name", "Segment", "Country", "City", "State", "Postal_Code",
                                         "Region", "Product_ID", "Category", "Sub_Category", "Product_Name", "Sales"])]
print(duplicateRows)

# To drop the 1 duplicated row
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Order_ID", "Order_Date", "Ship_Date", "Ship_Mode", "Customer_ID",
                                         "Customer_Name", "Segment", "Country", "City", "State", "Postal_Code",
                                         "Region", "Product_ID", "Category", "Sub_Category", "Product_Name", "Sales"]
                         , keep='first')
print(df2)

# To find out the rows with missing null values

null_data = df2[df2.isnull().any(axis=1)]
print(null_data)

# To remove rows with null values.
df3 = df2.dropna()
print(df3)

# To change the date format of Order_Date and Ship_Date
df3["Order_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df3["Order_Date"], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df3["Ship_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df3["Ship_Date"], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print(df3)
```

My output is desired but i receive a warning like

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

All i'm trying is to filter the dataframe where `Ship_Date>=Order_Date` What changes can be done in my code?

Thanks

Comment: How you get your `df3`?

Comment: I loaded the csv file into dataframe as this df3= pd.read_csv('xxx.csv') which contains Order_Date and Ship_Date columns

Comment: Have you filter the `df3` before `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: yes i just dropped the null values in df3 before trying to change the date format

Comment: How did you drop the null value, with `loc`?

Comment: I posted my whole code here.. Not sure how to use .loc for Order_Date,Ship_Date to do date format change?